# Have three significant decimal digits even with 0 and no decimals in R

Tags: r, significant-digits

I would like to return all numbers with 3 significant digits after the decimal, even if the third digit is zero.

For instance suppose I have

```
x <- 0.8579
y <- 0.21
z <- 924894.2595
```

Then if I do

```
x <- signif(x, digits=3) 
y <- signif(y, digits=3) 
z <- signif(z, digits=3)
```

I get `x = 0.857 y=0.21 and z=924894`

This is almost what I want. What i actually want is

```
x = 0.857 y=0.210 and z=924894
```

I have tried using

```
format(round(x,3), digits=3)
```

But doing this I get

```
x = 0.857 y=0.210 and z=924894.259
```

So now I have an issue on z, since I actually want `z=924894`.

Does anyone know of an answer in between to solve my issue?

Comment: You're doing this for reporting, right? Once you use `format` or similar, you no longer have numbers.

Comment: BTW, please be a little more mindful of the tags on your question, since the StackExchange tag recommendation is imperfect. I removed three tags that seem to have nothing directly to do with your question: [tag:dplyr], [tag:tidyverse], and [tag:readr].

Comment: Thank you SO UNBELIEVABLY much! sorry about the tags!

Comment: The tags are really minor, just bringing it to your attention in case you believed the tag-recommendation engine knew something you did not (it does not). Glad it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected "signif digits" for 924894 is not correct, though, since it is showing 6 signif digits. If you want to "violate" that technicality, then perhaps

```r
vec <- c(0.857,0.210,924894.259)
dig <- 3
sprintf(paste0("%0.", ifelse(vec >= (10^dig), "0", dig), "f"), vec)
# [1] "0.857"  "0.210"  "924894"
```

(I'm being a little sloppy with `ifelse` here: technically, `"0"` is character and `dig` is numeric/integer. This should be discouraged in general, and is *enforced* by `dplyr::if_else` and `data.table::fifelse`. This might mean that the return value from the `ifelse` expression may be `character` (if anything is large enough) or `integer`/`numeric` (if nothing is large enough); fortunately, however, `paste0` will deal with it exactly the same, so the slop of class-imprecision is acceptable here. If I wanted to be thorough, I'd use `as.character(dig)` instead.)

---

An alternative, that reacts to the apparent scale of each number individually:

```r
vec <- c(0.857,0.210,924894.259,1)
sprintf(paste0("%0.", pmax(floor(3 - log(abs(vec)+0.001, 10)), 0), "f"), vec)
# [1] "0.857"  "0.210"  "924894" "1.00"
```

Comment: Hey r2Evans, where exactly do you paste this? I keep gettting an error : "dig not found"

Comment: r2evans, I am super sorry but will go back to this...
In fact, it does not achieve the desired output. For instance, if i input it 1 it outputs 1.000 whereas it should output 1.00 (three digits of significance) do you have any idea?

Comment: Lola1993 see my edit, perhaps it's closer.

Comment: You're the best r2evans! Thank you so unbelievably much - I would have never figured it out myself!